# Baron Charles Cagniard de la Tour cannon experiment

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, history

I've found following description:

> In 1822 the French physicist Baron Charles Cagniard de la Tour was looking for an answer to the question: 'What happens when you boil a liquid in a sealed environment?'. He placed liquid ethanol and a ball bearing inside a sealed gun barrel and heated. Above a certain temperature he could no longer hear the liquid sloshing inside the tube when the barrel was moved. He had discovered the 'critical point' of the substance - the temperature above which it was neither liquid nor gas, but a single phase, a 'supercritical fluid'. [Source](https://edu.rsc.org/feature/supercritical-processing/2020235.article)

In other place

> [He was listening to the] sound of a rolling flint ball in a sealed cannon [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercritical_fluid)

What was the point of the ball bearing in this experiment? What was actually inside the cannon? Did anyone in modern-ish history try to reproduce this experiment (sounds like an epic YouTube video if you ask me)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about [hsm.se]

Comment: I disagree. This is a question about conducting a specific experiment.

Comment: I would say it requires knowledge of a specific experiment in the history of science and most physics students/professionals do not go into much depth on that or know how to research a history question properly (the sources for info are quite different).  I honestly think you'd get a better response on [hsm.se].